# apparmor has been DENIED (edoiting profile)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kernel, apparmor

I am trying to mount device inside docker/kubernetes pod.

I used device plugin to mount, and I am now making profiles for AppArmor
this is my code trying to mount

```
mkdir -p /home/worker/test
cd /home/worker
dd if=/dev/zero of=./test.img bs=10M count=1
mkfs.ext4 test.img
mount -o loop,ro test.img /home/worker/test
```

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1658991438.143:123): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed type match" error=-13 profile="mount" name="/home/worker/test/" pid=3709906 comm="mount" fstype="ext4" srcname="/dev/loop3" flags="ro"
```

So I added some options to profile, but it still doesn't works

```
      mount fstype=ext3 -> /home/worker/**,
      mount fstype=ext4 -> /home/worker/**,
      mount options in (r,ro,loop) ,
```

I think I added all options except "src name" section.
Will there be more recommended option?

Comment: You're usually not allowed to do mount(2) inside a container at all.  Mounting a loopback file is probably harmless (but also not especially useful), but if you're allowed to mount or unmount physical disks or bind-mount the real filesystem, you can escape the container and cause significant damage.

Comment: In order to mount local directory as a mount point check [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).  Also, [copying](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) might be useful.

Comment: I executed conatainer with capbilities - SYS_ADMIN. it works fine when I start container with apparmor:unconfined